# apache disable deflate module on a per site basis

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-deflate

Is there a way to disable the deflate module on a per site basis in Apache2?

I have a legacy website that uses custom mime type server side includes that are breaking with the deflate module enabled.  My guess is that the included file is being encrypted twice: once when included and then again when the response is sent.

I can disable the deflate module for Apache2 as a whole and the issue goes away, but I'd rather not be required to disable for all sites.

Has anyone had any success disabling deflate with an Apache conf directive?

**UPDATE**

I've successfully disabled DEFLATE for the virtual site using **SetEnv no-gzip 1**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/www/
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
    <Directory />
            Options +Includes
            SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
            AcceptPathInfo On

            AddType text/x-jbase-html .jhtml
            Action text/x-jbase-html /cgi-bin/jBase.pl
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Apache documentation you could set [internal variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html#special) `no-gzip` with [`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) directive to disable compression.

Comment: I've tried a number of combinations using no-gzip with no success.  Do you have suggestion for the directive syntax?

Comment: @gurun8 `SetEnv no-gzip` works for me (Apache 2.4.9).