# Apache2: apache2.conf rules for only one website ? ("virtualhost" websites)

Tags: apache2

I have multiple websites that I host on the same server (Apache2 / Debian). Therefore I use *VirtualHosts* (separate conf files in *site-available* folder) for each of my websites.

I would like to test the following directive (and other directives as well) that we normally put in a *apache2.conf*:

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

But only for one specifique website.

So my question is: how can I specify this directive to be applied for only one of my website ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apache disable deflate module on a per site basis](https://serverfault.com/questions/276131/apache-disable-deflate-module-on-a-per-site-basis)

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. Modules are loaded serverwide.